# DIY power 230v filament bulb off grid

Tags: solar-cell, inverter, batteries, incandescent

I need to power  a 230v bulb off the grid via solar power. Typically, I would have solar panels that charges some 12v dry/wet cells. These cells will have to supply an inverter that would power the bulb for 12 hours.

What are the considerations to achieve this, in terms of solar panel size and type, cell type and quantity and hours of incandescent light?

The area is in a tropical area, where seasons and daylight is not an issue except during monsoon. The relay control has its own cell and is not an issue too. However it sufficient power exists, I would like to connect the switching circuit cell to the solar power source too

Comment: Why a filament bulb, not a CFL or LED? For solar power, the 5-10x reduction in power consumption makes a huge difference to the cost of the system. Also, you could use a 12 V light and save the invertor...

Comment: @tomnexus has a point - the only reason to use a big lamp anymore is to cover pretty large spaces efficiently. CFL and LED will win the return-on-investment argument for almost all consumer applications these days.

Comment: @tomnexus. I disagree. New hybrid lamps are said to contain many toxic chemicals, much more than incandescents. And besides I need the filament bulb for heating purposes too, not just light.

Comment: See this link for the drawback of non-incandescent lamps http://phys.org/news/2015-02-japanese-traffic-cool-falls.html

Comment: Fair enough, if you need a filament bulb for a good reason, so be it. You were quite clear in the question. I just think that in most applications, particularly solar powered ones, the LED has far surpassed the filament light. Regarding toxic chemicals, consider the 5x increase in Pb that the incandescent requires. For traffic lights, that's a funny side effect! Should be solved by adding heaters - the LEDs aren't really there to save energy, they're brighter, quicker and don't fail all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is way simpler than it might sound to you right now.

You need to figure out the total number of watt hours that you need to supply to the load. Account for inverter efficiency - if none is known, assume 80 or 85 percent. Decide how long you can go without sunlight, and you can come up with an appropriate number of amp-hours capacity needed for your battery. Now decide how long you want it to take to regain full capacity on the battery and you can get an appropriate set of solar panels and a charge controller.

You would also want to consult an insolation table for information as to how much sunlight you can expect in your area per square meter. The table will be broken down into subsets based on conditions - for example, if you have a flat array pointed straight up at the sky versus one mounted on a slope.

Comment: Much appreciated, hope you could direct me to sources containing the necessary math.